# Tool tip text in Google App Maker

Tags: tooltip, google-app-maker

Is there a simpler way to do tool tip text when ever I hover thru the following **button** in Google App Maker?

[image: button]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the **Other** section of the **Property Editor**. The title field should give you what you need.

[image: 1]]

Answer (score 0):

This works well.  I know there is a way to inject JQuery into the AppMaker, and from there its just determining when the DOM is loaded and you can modify the element with a script.